# Where are the C and H atoms in 1,3,3,3-Tetrafluoropropene?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, structural-formula

I'm learning about refrigerants, and one refrigerant is  R-1234ze, otherwise known as 1,3,3,3-Tetrafluoropropene.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,3,3,3-Tetrafluoropropene), it says that the chemical formula is $\ce{C_3H_2F_4}$. But, Wikipedia also has the following diagram, which doesn't have any C or H atoms in it. Is there some sort of shorthand in these diagrams that omits C and H? Or, is this a typo on the Wikipedia article?

[image]

P.S. This was closed due to being a "homework question." I can see why people might think I am a freshman undergraduate trying to get a leg up on homework. However... I asked this because I am trying to get a handle on refrigerants and why they are so damaging to the climate, and what better refrigerants might look like. I already have a PhD in a different field, but I am a noob at chemistry.  I wish I had time to go back to school and build up a lot of chemistry knowledge!

Comment: It is the common convention C and H atoms are not drawn.  It is $\ce{F-CH=CH-CF3}$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I thought it must be something like that. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_formula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the common convention C and H atoms (attached to C) are not drawn.  It is $$\ce{F-CH=CH-CF3}$$

It comes particularly handy for complex structures of sacharides and other molecules in biochemistry.